# Как в этом шаблон поменять местами логотип и бургер-меню?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, шаблоны

Помогите пожалуйста.
Как в этом шаблоне:
https://page.ninjamail.click/bbd90894-b711-4d53-b1cf-486c29b83971/
поменять местами бургер и логотип?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проще всего будет добавить `flex-direction: row-reverse;` в определенном брейкпойнте на элемент с классом `t280__menu__content`.

Comment: @Simon спасибо. помогло.

Comment: @Simon вылезла другая проблема. попробуйте открыть мобильное меню с изменениями https://page.ninjamail.click/bbd90894-b711-4d53-b1cf-486c29b83971/

Comment: И в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: @Simon мобильное меню не раскрывается на всю ширину.

Comment: Честно говоря, я понятия не имею как оно должно выглядеть и как выглядело изначально. Если убрать `flex-direction: row-reverse;` то текст меню у меня вообще вне экрана получается.